# Capture words, digits and hyphen in scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string that contains words/digits and can optionally contain hyphen in the middle. I am trying to capture this string using regex in Scala.
I tried `[\w\d-]+` and `[\w\d\-]+` but this is always returning null. How can I capture words/digits with hyphen?

e.g.input string=Abc1-LT.json

usage:

```
val pattern = """^([\w\d-]+).json$""".r
pattern.findFirstMatchIn(name) match {
      case Some(m) => try{
          m.subgroups.mkString("-")
      }
..
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using your regex to match strings?

Comment: val pattern = """^([\w\d]).json$""".r

Comment: Where is the `+` in your regex?

Comment: edited original with the usage

Comment: Does your input  really start with space? That won't match with this regex. Also the way you seem to want to use this (concatenate parts by `-`) will do nothing, it matches only a single group, nothing to combine.

Comment: No space at the beginning.

Comment: If there can be 1 or 0 hyphens, use `"""^(\w+)(?:-(\w+))?\.json$""".r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in Scala, compiled regex patterns are anchored by default, so the `^` and `$` are not needed. And `\d` is a subset of `\w` so that's not needed either.

Next, there is only one capture group in your pattern so there can be only one entry in the `subgroups` result. That means that `mkString()` can't place anything between the groups because there is no between.

Lastly, there's an easier way to extract a singe capture group.

```
val pattern = """([\w-]+).json""".r

name match {
  case pattern(sub) => s"-->$sub<--"  //res0: String = -->Abc1-LT<--
  case _ => "no match"
}
```